# return a single object in an object array

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'm new to programming and I was wondering how do you return a single object from an object array
This is the part of the code I'm having trouble in:

```
public Class methodName(){
    x = 3;
    if(array[x] != null){
        Class y = array[x];
    }
    return y;
}
```

it gives me an error on the "y"

```
y cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Comment: java is block scoped not function scoped.  you can fix by declaring `y` before the `if` block with a default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `y` is declared inside of the `if`, it's unavailable outside of the `if`.

Declare it outside of the `if` with a default value, then reassign it inside the `if`:

```
public Class methodName(){
    x = 3;
    Class y = null; // Defaults to null if not reassigned later
    if(array[x] != null){
        y = array[x]; // Reassign the pre-declared y here if necessary
    }
    return y;
}
```

This will return the default `null` if `array[x] == null`.

Look up how variables are scoped to learn what's going on here. Basically, if a variable is declared within a `{}`, it can't be used outside of the `{}` (although that's a gross over-simplification).